# NodeJS cannot connect to MongoDB on server ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a basic script which is test for connecting to database.

When I'm trying to run the script with `node Connection.js` the script's run, but I don't receive the response in console that `successfully connected to the database` and as well with that I don't receive any error. It's just looks like the script runs but nothing happens.

On VPS I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I allowed the IP address and port from my local machine.

Any ideas what's wrong with this one, I was trying to find anything related this topic but unsuccessful

**Connection.js**

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// this is our MongoDB database
const dbRoute =
    'mongodb://username:password@ip.adress:22/CryptoCurrencies';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// connects our back end code with the database
mongoose.connect(dbRoute, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));
```

**EDIT1**

I edited the code and I 100% sure that I allow on my ubuntu server `port 22` but I still can't connect to my VPS with Node

I receive this error - `(node:10115) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED`

Any ideas on how I can fix this one? Username and password are correct, DB name is also correct, ip address and port as well. Currently I totally don't understand what is wrong. I check tons of resources to solve that and just connect my NodeJS script from local machine to VPS server.

Comment: `'mongodb://server.ip.adress:port'` - you are using the actual address and port, aren't you?

Comment: @RameshReddy Absolutely. All correct suppose to be, I checked Firewall for port and IP.  I whitelist it and still. Script runs, but nothings happened, I also doesn't receive any error. When I'm trying to run it on localhost like 127.0.0.1 it runs.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the mongodb using the mongo-shell? And *does* the script  exit or does it hang?

Comment: @eol the script is hangs and yes I'm able to connect via mongoshell

Comment: Weird, I tested your code on my machine with (`mongodb://localhost:27017`) and it works as expected. Pretty sure that it's some kind of networking/firewall issue.

Comment: @eol it works on localhost as well. Going to try enable firewall for all ports to see. Otherwise I don't understand the problem at all.

Comment: if its not local mongo. are you missing database auth? `mongodb://user:pass@server.ip.adress:port`

Comment: @NathanBoaldin Hello, thanks for your suggestion. I edited the main question now you can take a look on it.

Comment: 22 is the default port for ssh, are you sure you have configured mongodb to listen on port 22? The default port for mongodb is 27017

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your DB with MongoDB Compass? It has a nifty feature - you can just copy your connection string and try to connect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be some issues with the configuration on server. Please go through these checklist for issues.

- MongoDb by default run on port no 27017, and port number 22 is reserved for SSH, please make sure you are connecting to right port number.
- Please make sure that you MongoDB server instance is listening to all network interfaces, IP addresses if you are connecting to server via network. Check your mongod.conf (or mongodb.conf) file (`bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` for local only, `bind_ip = 0.0.0.0` to listen traffic from all network interfaces.) for more details.
- If you are connecting via SSH it require username and password of user on ubuntu OS & connecting directly with mongodb require the username name password for user defined on mongo server instance.
- Please check that authorization settings is enabled on your mongo instance mongod.conf(or mongodb.conf) file.
- Please make sure that the user you created have access on the the database (`CryptoCurrencies` the one you are connecting to)

Check this link on how to configure auth on MongoDB server instance https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-b9e8a924efac

Answer (score 3):

I'm kind of sure your VPS must have the port 22 bound to openssh-server... Are you sure you've been able to start mongod correctly and it's listening on port 22?

BTW, all services under 1024 are kind of standardized you should always try to use ports above 1024.

Could you share with us the configuration of your mongod?